# How to focus parent terminal tab of shell script for input?

Tags: applescript, command-line, automation, zsh

I have a zsh script where I prompt for user input every 15 minutes. How can I make the tab of Terminal that the script is running in open up / focus? `open -a Terminal` just opens the whole window.

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26222820/4941530) trick to get current application and re-open it, is there a way to extend it to tabs/sessions?

```sh
term=$(/usr/bin/osascript -e "copy path to frontmost application as text to stdout")
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application $term to activate'
```

Also aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986839/4941530) trick to go back to an old tab, although (1) I couldn't get it to work and (2) I need the data in stdout so zsh can use it.

```
osascript \
    -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set oldTab to the selected tab of the front window' \
    -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down' \
    -e 'delay 1' \
    -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set selected of oldTab to true'
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is you are trying to do? Are you trying to have the _shell script_ itself refocus the _tab/window_ in which the _shell script_ is running? In other word, do you want to start the _shell script_ and when the 15 minutes are up, regardless of what app is frontmost, you want **Terminal** to come frontmost to the _tab/window_ in which the _shell script_ is running and this all be done programmatically?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Well put.

Comment: Big sur (11.4).

Comment: Can you share the _shell script_ or at least lay it out a bit and how you have the timer set/running in the _shell script_?

Comment: Yeah right now it's just a `sleep 900`. So I do some processing and tasks, display some data, get input with `read`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply of "Yes, precisely. Well put." to my comment under the OP...

> <sup>Could you please clarify what it is you are trying to do? Are you trying to have the shell script itself refocus the tab/window in which the shell script is running? In other word, do you want to start the shell script and when the 15 minutes are up, regardless of what app is frontmost, you want **Terminal** to come frontmost to the tab/window in which the shell script is running and this all be done programmatically?</sup>

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* used in conjunction with `osascript` in a `zsh` *shell script* should do as wanted. Obviously the value of the `sleep` *command* is just for testing purposes, use whatever it is you are now using as the timer within your current `zsh` *shell script*.

```
#!/bin/zsh

    # First line of code of shell script.

winID="$(osascript -e 'id of window 1 of app "Terminal"')"

    # Function to refocus window of running script.

refocusWindow() {

        # Code to refocus window of the
        # running shell script using the 
        # window id retrieved from the first 
        # line of code in the shell script.

    osascript <<EOS
    tell app "Terminal"
        set frontmost of windows whose id = $winID to true
        activate
    end tell
EOS
}

# Do some stuff...
# Your other code goes here.

sleep 5

refocusWindow
```

---

**Notes:**

In **Terminal**, it does not matter how may *tabs/windows* there are as there is only one `tab` per `window`, even if the window appears to have multiple **tabs**.  In other words, asking **Terminal** to `count windows` and `count tabs of windows` will *return* the same *number*. Thus there it no need to *loop* thru `tabs` to achieve the goal herein, just `windows`, and actually in this case there really is no need to *loop* thru `windows`.

Note that **macOS Sierra** what the last version in which **Terminal** supported multiple `tabs` of a `window` programmatically. In other words, from the **UI** a single **window** with two **tabs** there would be `tab 1 of window 1` and `tab 2 of window 1`, but since **macOS High Sierra** from the **UI** a single **window** with two **tabs** there would be `tab 1 of window 1` and `tab 1 of window 2`, and thus no longer the need to *loop* thru `tabs`.

There is all so no need to do something like `set selected of tab j of window i to true` as once a given `window` is set `frontmost`, the value of `tab 1 of window i` is already set to `true` as a result.

The *example* **shell script** and **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Terminal** as an executable *shell script* under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

As we do not know how you have your `zsh` *shell script* coded, you'll have to work in the *code* presented herein to suite your needs.

Comment: @Luke Miles, I've reworked the AppleScript code to more directly set the target window running the _shell script_ to be frontmost. There was really no need to _loop_ anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little awkward since I can't run this code from within your script (nor within an applescript) but this osascript should allow you to specify a desired tab (tp) and switch to it from any other within the same window.

```
osascript -e '
tell application "Terminal" to set tp to item 1 of (tabs of window 1 whose selected is true)
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
delay 1
tell application "Terminal" to set selected of tp to true'
```

I think your issue was just a syntax one: e.g. `selected tab` versus `tab whose selected is true`.

Each line does the following:

- Sets variable tp to the active tab
- Creates a new tab using system events
  (which becomes the active tab)
- Delay 1
- Makes tp the active tab

The variable tp will resemble this:

```
--> tab 3 of window id 360 of application "Terminal"
```

Note, there are some alternatives to setting tp to the active tab but they're more complex.

Comment: Hmm this seems to do nothing for me?

Comment: @Luke Miles, RE: "Hmm this seems to do nothing for me?" --  the original _code_ posted in this answer had a trailing space after each `\\`  and is what caused it to fail.

Comment: Mockman, You can not have a trailing space after a `\\` as you did in the original _code_ of your answer as it causes the execution thereof to fail. If you use a code editor that understands shell scripting it should so an error of having a trailing space in this use case.

Comment: I meant to say that the current code (one big string without backslashes) seems to not bring focus back to the old tab, sorry for being unclear

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks. My intent was for visual formatting so that it the four elements could be seen (rather than ease of copy/paste). It is easy enough to strip out the line endings (I hope).

Comment: @LukeMiles What does happen when you run the command?

Comment: It makes a new tab correctly and if I add a line at the end that's just 'tp' then it prints "tab 1 of window id 9398", but the old tab is not being selected

Comment: What about this, on its own? 'tell application "Terminal" to set selected of item 1 of (tabs of window 1) to true'

Comment: Seems to have no effect and give no errors. Strange.

Comment: This paradigm `set selected of tab x of window y to true` has not been valid since **macOS High Sierra**, as **Terminal** in **macOS Sierra** was the last to programmatically support `tab x of window y`.  In other words, from the **UI** a single **window** with two **tabs** there would be `tab 1 of window 1` and `tab 2 of window 1`, but since **macOS High Sierra** from the **UI** a single **window** with two **tabs** there would be `tab 1 of window 1` and `tab 1 of window 2`. While it was not known what version of **macOS** the OP was using when you posted, he's using **macOS Big Sur**.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for bringing that to light. I'm using Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one inelegant way to do it, adapted from a decade-old SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047748/select-a-particular-tab-in-terminal-depending-upon-the-content-using-applescript/5049859#5049859):

```bsh
open_this_tab() {
    rand_string=$(openssl rand -base64 12)
    echo $rand_string
    osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"
        set allWindows to number of windows

        repeat with i from 1 to allWindows
            set allTabs to number of tabs of window i
            repeat with j from 1 to allTabs
                if contents of tab j of window i contains '"\"$rand_string\""' then
                    set frontmost of window i to true
                    set selected of tab j of window i to true
                end if
            end repeat
        end repeat
        end tell'
}
```

Testing it out:

```
sleep 3
# (go to a different window or tab)
open_this_tab
```